# Execute stand alone python script inside another script

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-exec

I have made a .py file (i call it acomp.py) that reads from and SQL database and after a series of calculations and exports its output to an excel file.Later I sends this .xlsx file by e-mail to various persons.

I wish to put it inside another python script so I can use the schedule module to call acomp.py aromatically at selected times, run it and send the output by email:

```
def exec_scrpit():
    exec(open("acomp.py", encoding='utf-8').read())
    send_email()

schedule.every().day.at("07:20").do(exec_scrpit)
```

When the second script calls the fist it messes with the acom.py internal functions returning the error:

```
"  File "<string>", line 125, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'modalidade_contrato' is not defined"
```

This 'modalidade_contrato' is defined inside acomp.py and it runs perfectly when I execute acom.py directly.

Any ideia how should I proceed? I think my whole strategy is not usual, but I have to do it this way because I do not have admin privileges on my computer.

Comment: What is Modalidade_contrato? A class? A function? A module?

Comment: it is a function. I call it inside a lambda function of the acomp.py file.

Answer (score 1):

I learned that you can simply run it as you would in cmd:

```
os.system(r'"C:\Users\user.name\Miniconda3\python.exe acomp.py"')
```